# HOW TO RELOAD THE VIEW BUT NOT DATA IN VIEWPAGER

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here is the case:-

I have navigation drawer with view pager on Main Activity(or Home Screen). There are multiple items(**these items comes from server**) to select from list inside fragment. Suppose I select 3 items and click submit button then I move to next fragment(where I fill person contact info) and once user click on button to confirm his detail, all the information with 3 selected items saved on server.

I want to go on Home Screen once user confirmed but do not want to call webservice again for the items.

**In other words, want to reload the view without being selected any item or call to server.**

Comment: Use ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: Can u give an example?